# Types of Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There are different types of integration, such as Riemann, Lebesgue, etc. How about differentiation: Are there different types of differentiation? If not, why not?

Comment: Differentiation can be generalized by distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))